# Display Google translate widget after button click

Tags: javascript, html, widget

I need to load and display the Google translate widget after a button was clicked. How to do that?

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en',
    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Btw: What is it with that **//** URL they used in **//translate.google.com**?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to load the French toolbar:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=fr&u=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F'><img src="button.png" border="0"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can add a button in the google_translate_element and use getScript to load the translate script from Google and run the googleTranslateElementInit function only after the button is clicked.

```
$("#google_translate_element button").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    var url = "//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit";
    $.getScript(url);   
});
```

Maintain the code as shown in the original question but remove the `<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>` as that is what you want to suppress on the page load and initiate on the button click.

if you want to add a button somewhere other than within the google_translate_element, you'll have to adjust or remove the  `$(this).hide();` part of the above code.

This saves a significant amount of time on the page load as the Google Translate script takes a lot of time to load.  Using it in this way avoids loading it by default and is only added if the user requests it.