# How to load Google Translate widget on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-translate

I'm using Google Translate Widget on my website but I don`t want it to load when the page is loading because it's slowing the loading speed and is not used that often. I would like to have a image instead and only if I click that image to load the widget.

For now, I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


 function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'ro',
      includedLanguages: 'af,ar,de,en,es,fr,hu,it,ja,no,ro,ru,tr,zh-CN',
      layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE,
      autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element');
  }

  var googleTranslateScript = document.createElement('script');
  googleTranslateScript.type = 'text/javascript';
  googleTranslateScript.async = true;
  googleTranslateScript.src = 'http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit';
  ( document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] ).appendChild(googleTranslateScript);
</script>
```

Can somebody help ?

Comment: See below link it may help you
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095971/display-google-translate-widget-after-button-click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095971/display-google-translate-widget-after-button-click)

Comment: I don't get it!  :| . I can`t find an answer to solve this problem in that post.

Comment: Are you really using jQuery, because all I can see is native JavaScript; this isn't a criticism but if you'd rather not use jQuery then you might want to remove that tag.

Comment: I have no idea .... what tag ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the script loading part inside a function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'ro',
      includedLanguages: 'af,ar,de,en,es,fr,hu,it,ja,no,ro,ru,tr,zh-CN',
      layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE,
      autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element');
  }

  function loadGoogleTranslate() {
    var googleTranslateScript = document.createElement('script');
    googleTranslateScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    googleTranslateScript.async = true;
    googleTranslateScript.src = 'http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] ).appendChild(googleTranslateScript);
  }
</script>
```

Then you either add a click handler to your script, or use html onclick, eg:

```
<img onclick="loadGoogleTranslate(); this.remove()">
```

Comment: Thank you for this code. I tried, When I click the image, the script is loading but the image still remains and every time I click on it, it's opening new translate widgets. I don`t know how to solve this :|

Comment: It`s working! Thank you! . Is there a way I can make to show a hand when I hover the mouse over the image ?

Comment: yeah, use css... img {cursor: pointer} or inline <img style="cursor: pointer;"  ....

Comment: I have this but it's not working: <button onclick="loadGoogleTranslate(); this.remove()"><img id="gtranslate_img" src="images/gtranslate.png" style="margin-top:-4px; cursor: pointer;"></button>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108713/discussion-between-forforce-and-yezzz).

Comment: sorry, wasn't here... but I see you found my last edit